# Finding a element with a fake attribute that was added

Tags: jquery, attributes, find

I added a fake attribute to all my elements on the page, for example `myId=100`, each element has a different fake id.
Now i need to find an element according to the fake id, is this possible?
I tried doing

```
$("#myFrame").contents().find('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr['myid'] === 100) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Any better ideas?
thank you

Comment: Whatever your problem was, I can't believe this was the best solution.

Comment: Will your fake id's compile? Are **classes** so bad?

Comment: I'm interested on your part of the script that assigns to all *a* a *fake id*. Could you post it in an edit?

Comment: @roXon Sorry i cant give it to you cuz i dont have it, i only have the site after the fake id was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).attr['myid']` should be `$(this).attr('myid')` (`attr` is a function).

You can also use the [*attribute selector*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("#myFrame").contents().find('a[myId="100"]').hide();
```

---

You should avoid adding custom attributes to HTML elements. If you explain the problem we might be able to suggest a better way.

Comment: also if i want the .each() to go through all DOM elements (not only a) how do i do that?

Comment: If you only want to do something on an element with a specific ID, then just omit the `a`: `$("#myFrame").contents().find('[myId="100"]')`. Otherwise use `*` instead of `a`: `$("#myFrame").contents().find('*')`. But looping over every element takes time. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a custom attribute, do it the HTML5 way:

```
<span data-id="blahblah">Foo</span>


alert($(this).data("id")); // blahblah
```

See http://api.jquery.com/data/